# Is there a such a way to know how much memory space a file would take?

Tags: perl

Is there a such a way to know how much memory space a file would take before hand?
For example, lets say I have a file size of 1G bytes. How would this file size translate to memory size?

Comment: It surely depends on what you do with the data from that file. Can you give some more context?

Comment: I'm just speaking in gernal. I take this file (for example, say a text file) and load it into memory. Does this mean the memory would be 1G bytes also.

Answer (score 4):

I take your example from the comment and elaborate on what might happen to a text file when loaded into memory: Some time ago, "text" usually meant ASCII (as the least common denominator at least). And lots of software, written in a language like C, would represent such ASCII strings as an `char*` type. This resulted in a more-or-less exact match in memory requirements: Every byte in the input file would occupy one byte when loaded into RAM.

But that has changed in the last years with the rise of Unicode. The same text file, loaded by a simple Java program (and using Java's [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) type, which is very likely) would take up *two times* the amount of RAM. This is so, because the Java `String` type represents each character internally using UTF-16 (16 bits per character minimum), whereas ASCII used only one byte per character.

What I'm trying to say here is: There is no easy answer to your question, it *always* depends on who reads the data and what he's about to do with it.

One thing is true quite often: by "loading", the data does not become smaller.

Comment: If the file is already encoded in UTF8, and loaded as UTF8, there shouldn't be any change in its internal representation, should there? Perl's UTF8 represents chr(0..127) as 1 byte, and 128+ as more, but that price should already be built into the file, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidO: Wow, I wrote all this text and did not notice this question was Perl - specific. I'll let it here because I think it still points out the issues with doing such an estimate. It's universal, regardless of the language used. Just my example isn't the best match. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you read the whole file into memory at once, you'll need at least the size of the file free memory. Much of the time people don't actually need to do so, they just don't know another way. For an explanation of the problem and alternatives see:

http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/01/memory-map-files-instead-of-slurping-them/

Answer (score 1):

You can check yourself by writing a little test script with [Memory::Usage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Memory%3a%3aUsage).

From its documentation's synopsis:

```
use Memory::Usage;
my $mu = Memory::Usage->new();

# Record amount of memory used by current process
$mu->record('starting work');

# Do the thing you want to measure
$object->something_memory_intensive();

# Record amount in use afterwards
$mu->record('after something_memory_intensive()');

# Spit out a report
$mu->dump();
```

Then you'll know how much your build of Perl, given whatever character encoding you intend to use, and whatever method of dealing with the file you intend to implement, will consume in memory.

If you can avoid loading the whole file at once, and instead just iterate over it line by line or record by record, the memory concern goes away.  So it would help to know what you actually are trying to accomplish.  You may have an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

`perldoc -f stat`

```
   stat    Returns a 13-element list giving the status info for a file,
           either the file opened via FILEHANDLE or DIRHANDLE, or named by
           EXPR.  If EXPR is omitted, it stats $_.  Returns the empty list
           if "stat" fails.  Typically used as follows:

               ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
                  $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
                      = stat($filename);
```

Note the `$size` return value. It is the size of the file in bytes. If you are going to slurp the entire file into memory you will need at least $size bytes. Then again, you might need a whole lot more (or even a whole lot less), depending on what you do to the contents of the file.